# Whats wrong with this htaccess line

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have these lines in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^restaurant_pos$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

but if you visit the site [here](http://50.57.119.54/restaurant_pos) then you will see the top left corner my php debug statement

```
echo print_r($_REQUEST);
```

which prints

```
Array
(
    [route] => 
)
```

Why is it empty.....this is causing issues...what am i doing wrong

Comment: Is `$1` the value you're trying to assign the route param?

Comment: I want to assign "restaurant_pos"

Comment: @Tamer if you want to assign "restaurant_pos" to `$1` then you have to put it in brackets `RewriteRule ^(restaurant_pos)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]`

Comment: so brackets make the $1 available ...so if i have 2 () brackets then I can reference $2 im guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
RewriteRule ^restaurant_pos$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Comment: so Do brackets make the $1 available ...so if i have 2 () brackets then I can reference $2

Comment: Yes. `()` are used to match conditions, so e.g. `^(.*)/(.*)$` will let you rewrite to `index.php?route=$1&second=$2`

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing a replacement variable `$1` which does not exist. These are defined with parenthesis, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^restaurant_pos_([0-9]+)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

This will for example match a number in the url after `restaurant_pos` and put it into the GET parameter `route`.

```
http://www.example.com/restaurant_pos_1234
```

will result in

```
index.php?route=1234
```

Or if you are trying to get everything:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1
```

should return everything after the domain name in the GET parameter `route`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$0` instead. Alternatively, try to add a capturing group (parenthesis around whatever should go in `$1`).

```
RewriteRule ^(restaurant_pos)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```